# Does confluent kafka provide an api for streaming, grouping and aggregation in python?

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, stream-processing

Does confluent kafka provide an api for streaming, grouping and aggregation in python language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*There's no such thing as "Confluent Kafka". Confluent Platform is a distribution of Apache Kafka®, along with other components such as the Schema Registry, KSQL, etc.*

---

Apache Kafka includes the Kafka Streams API, which is only available for Java and Scala.

Options that you have for stream processing include:

- [Faust](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/ksql) (called via the REST API from Python)

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent.*